# String tokens do not appear to be either stored or accessed right in my C program

Tags: c, shell, segmentation-fault, strtok, strlen

I am trying to build a simple shell program in C.  I have posted recently about this, but my program has changed a bit since then.  I can edit my previous question if need be, but I really just want to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm kind of embarrassed at the way my code looks.  It feels bulky and convoluted but I just don't know what to do to make it any smaller, but I can't even get it right as it currently is.

I want to take user input, and break it up into shell arguments that can be passed to execvp eventually.  I need to be able to differentiate between input with no '|' and '>' chars, and input with them.  At the moment, it appears that something I'm doing is causing a seg-fault.  But I'm not sure what to make of the error message gdb gives me.

Any criticism or tips would be greatly appreciated here.  I have been beating my head over this thing for awhile now and just really want to understand.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
#1  0x00007ffff7e4b5b4 in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:35
#2  0x000055555555573a in tokenizeInput ()
#3  0x0000555555555471 in main ()
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SZ 1024

void checkForPipe(char *string, bool *pipe_bool);
void checkForRedirect(char *string, bool *redirect_bool);
void tokenizeInput(char *string,
                                     char **argz,
                                     bool *pipe,
                                     bool *redirect,
                                     int *stats);
void executeCommand(int *stats, char **argz);

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    bool is_pipe = false;
    bool is_redirect_out = false;
    bool is_exit = false;
    int status = 0;           //Will determine how to execute execvp()
    char *args[100] = {NULL};

    ptr = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    while(!is_exit)
    {
        // Diplay prompt
        char cur_dir[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        getcwd(cur_dir, MAX_BUF_SZ);
        printf("SHELL:%s$ ", cur_dir);
        printf("%d\n", status);

        fgets(ptr, MAX_BUF_SZ, stdin);
        checkForPipe(ptr, &is_pipe);
        checkForRedirect(ptr, &is_redirect_out);
        printf("pipe flag = %d\n", is_pipe);
        printf("redirect flag = %d\n", is_redirect_out);
        if(strcmp(ptr, "exit\n") == 0)
        {
            is_exit = true;
        }
        tokenizeInput(ptr, args, &is_pipe, &is_redirect_out, &status);
        printf("is token being called?\n");
        executeCommand(&status, args);
        printf("is execute being called?\n");
        printf("%d\n", status);

    }

    return 0;

}

void checkForPipe(char *string, bool *pipe_bool)
{
    char *check_for_pipes;
    char *clean_compare;
    check_for_pipes = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);
    clean_compare = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(check_for_pipes, string);
    strcpy(clean_compare, string);

    char * token = strtok(check_for_pipes, "|");

    if(strcmp(token, clean_compare) == 0)
        {
         free(clean_compare);
         free(check_for_pipes);
        }

    else
    {
        *pipe_bool = 1;
        free(clean_compare);
        free(check_for_pipes);
    }
}

void checkForRedirect(char *string, bool *redirect_bool)
{
    char *check_for_redirects;
    char *clean_compare;
    check_for_redirects = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);
    clean_compare = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(check_for_redirects, string);
    strcpy(clean_compare, string);

    char * token = strtok(check_for_redirects, ">");

    if(strcmp(token, clean_compare) == 0)
        {
         free(clean_compare);
         free(check_for_redirects);
        }

    else
    {
        *redirect_bool = 1;
        free(clean_compare);
        free(check_for_redirects);
    }

}

void tokenizeInput(char *string,
                                     char **argz,
                                   bool *pipe,
                                     bool *redirect,
                                     int *stats)
{
    int i = 0;
        if(*pipe == false && *redirect == false)
        {
            char *token = strtok(string, " \n");
            argz[i] = token;

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                i++;
                argz[i] = token;
                
                printf("%s\n", argz[i]);
            }
            i = 0;
            *stats = 1; //1 indicates no pipe or redirect
        }

        else if(*pipe == true && *redirect == false)
        {
            char *token = strtok(string, "|\n");
            argz[i] = token;

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, "|\n");
                i++;
                argz[i] = token;
            }
            *stats = 2; // 2 indicates a sole pipe
            *pipe = false;
        }

        else if(*pipe == false && *redirect == true)
        {
            char *token = strtok(string, ">\n");
            argz[i] = token;

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, ">\n");
                i++;
                argz[i] = token;
            }
            *stats = 3; // 3 indicates a sole redirect
            *redirect = false;
        }

        else if(*pipe == true && *redirect == true)
        {
            char *token = strtok(string, "|>\n");
            argz[i] = token;

            while (token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, "|>\n");
                i++;
                argz[i] = token;
            }
            *stats = 4; // 4 indicates a pipe and a redirect
            *pipe = false;
            *redirect = false;
        }
}

void executeCommand(int *stats, char **argz)
{
    if(*stats == 1)
    {
                printf("this is the value stored in arg 0 %s\n", argz[0]);
                printf("this is the value stored in arg 1 %s\n", argz[1]);
                pid_t child_pid = fork();

                if(child_pid < 0)
                {
                    //Forking Error!
                    printf("Forking Error Occured!\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
                else if(child_pid == 0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", argz[0]);
                    if(execvp(argz[0],argz) == -1)
                    {
                        printf("Error running command\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    wait(NULL);
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: Failing to check the return value of `fgets` is just asking for trouble. It appears you may be trying to parse buffer that is not null terminated.

Comment: `malloc` returns uninitialized memory. Consider using `calloc`.

Comment: Are you using `-Wall` or `-Werror` when you compile? My `gcc` foo is very rusty, but I think you're either ignoring a lot of warnings, or you don't have them dialed up high enough.

Comment: @jwdonahue - actually compiles without a single warning with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11` -- so that part is fine. You can replace the entire `checkForPipe(ptr, &is_pipe);` function with a simple `if (strchr (ptr, '|') is_pipe = true;` and there are several of those cleanups.

Comment: Try using `-g` to compile with debug information so your stack trace will give you line info.

Comment: Also, in `tokenizeInput()`, you are throwing away the first token you get with `char *token = strtok(string, " \n");` -- is that intended? Since there are no copies of tokens, each token points to an address within `ptr`. And since there is no copy of `ptr` made, the memory is sprinkled with `'\0'` characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No that's not intentional.  It's probably contributing to some of my run-time problems.

Answer (score 2):

How to read the error:

```
// SIGSEGV means it is a pointer operation.
//
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
//
// ... while trying to get the length of a string.
//
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65      ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
//
//  str=0x0 _> ah ah!  It's a NULL pointer error.  In an I/O put() function
//  since you do not open files, that's probably in a call to printf().  
//  One of its arguments is NULL
//
#1  0x00007ffff7e4b5b4 in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:35
//
//  The function called from main is tokenizeInput().
//
#2  0x000055555555573a in tokenizeInput ()
#3  0x0000555555555471 in main ()
```

I think the error is in tokenizeInput(), but there are plenty more candidates, that will fail in the same way all through your code.  You MUST check the result of strtok() before using it.

Your use of strtok for finding a single symbol forces you to allocate memory and create a copy, for finding a symbol in a string, use strchr().  Your checkForRedirect() function then becomes...

```
// why pass a pointer for the result ? Wouldn't this be easier to work with?
bool checkForRedirect(const char* string)
{
    return strchr(string, '>') != NULL;
}

// in yours, this test doesn't quite make any sense.. apart from the fact that 
// token could be NULL, and you don't test for it, the string token != clean_compare 
// always if token is not NULL at this point.
//
char* token = strtok(check_for_redirects, ">");   // token could be NULL
if(strcmp(token, clean_compare) == 0)             // SIGSEGV here
// should be:
if (token && strcmp(token, ...
```

Here is where your code crashes now, it's very similar.

```
void tokenizeInput(char *string, char **argz, bool *pipe, bool *redirect, int *stats)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (!*pipe && !*redirect)
    {
        char *token = strtok(string, " \n");
        argz[i] = token;

        while (token != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            i++;
            argz[i] = token;
            
            // At some point, token is NULL
            printf("%s\n", argz[i]);  // At some point, token is NULL, this fails.
        }  
        i = 0;
        *stats = 1; //1 indicates no pipe or redirect
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Maybe rewriting the loop will help.

```
/* ... */
char *token = NULL;
int i = 0;
for (token = strtok(string, " \n"), i = 0; token; token = strtok(NULL, " \n"), ++i)
{
    argz[i] = token;            // token is never NULL here.
    printf(argz[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
/* ... */
```

[EDIT]

I think you are taking this problem from the wrong end...  What you really have is a command line containing one or more commands to execute, separated by a pipe symbol, and optionally terminated by a direct output to file symbol '>' and a file name.

step 1 would be to separate the possible redirection file from the rest.

step 2 parse all commands.

step 3 go through the commands, create and connect pipes, create and plug
in the optional redirection file.

step 4 execute the operations stack.

step 5 cleanup.

```
/* ... */
// your command data
struct _command_t
{
    const char** argv;
    int argc;
    int in_pipe;     // file descriptors for i/O
    int out_pipe;
} command_t;

char* input_line;
char* cmd;
char* ptr;

command_t* temp_command;

// an array to store commands.
command_t* commands = (command_t*)malloc(max_commands * sizeof(command_t));

int max_commands = 16;
int commands_count = 0;

// a string for file to redirect output to.
const char* redir_file = NULL;

/* ... */

for (;;)
{
    commands_count = 0;

    fgets(input_line, MAX_BUF_SZ, stdin);

    // first get redirection, if any 
    if ((str = strchr(input_line, '>') != NULL)
    {
        if ((redir_file = parse_redir_filename(str + 1)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("error parsing redir file.\n");
            exit(3);
        }
        *str = 0;  // truncate input line
    }

    // here's one reason strtok is not well-suited for this task...
    // what happens if cmd does not have a closing '\n' symbol?

    for (cmd = strtok(input_line, "|\n"); cmd; cmd = strtok(NULL, "|\n"))
    {
        if (commands_count >= max_commands)
        {
            temp_commands = (command_t*)realloc(commands, (max_commands + 16) * sizeof(command_t));
            if (!temp_commands)
            {
                printf("out of memory\n");
                exit(3);
            }
            commands = temp_commands;
            max_commands += 16;
        }

        memset(&(commands[commands_count]), 0, sizeof(command_t));

        // assuming parse_command returns negative on error
        if (parse_command(cmd, commands[commands_count] < 0)
        {
            printf("error parsing command \"%s\".\n", cmd);
            exit(3);
        }
        ++commands_count;
    }

    if (commands_count == 0)
        break;

    /* process the command stack ... */
}
```

This is a rather naive parser for files *and* arguments, it should work in most cases.

```
   // returns null-terminated token, 
    // on exit, str is advanced to symbol following token.
    const char* parse_token(char** str)
    {
        const char* result = NULL;

        // skip whitespace
        while (**str != 0 && isspace(**str & 0xFF))
            ++(*str);

        if (**str == 0)
            return NULL;

        if (**str == '\'')
        {
            result = ++(*str);

            // skip to closing quote
            while (**str != 0 && **str != '\'')
                ++(*str);

            // validate and null terminate
            if (**str != '\'')
                return NULL;

            **str = 0;
            ++(*str);

            /* here, you may want to check if it's a file or dir name */ 
        }
        else
        {
            result = *str;
            while (**str != 0 && !isspace(**str & 0xFF))
                ++(*str);

            // null terminate (clobbering whitespace)
            if (**str != 0)
            {
                **str = 0;
                ++(*str);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Parsing the redir file name.

```
   const char* parse_redir_filename(char* str)
   {
       const char* result = parse_token(&str);
       if (!result)
           return NULL;

       // make sure we have either nothing or whitespace following.
       while (*str != 0)
           if (!isspace(*(str++) & 0xFF))
               return NULL;

       return result;
   }
```

Parsing each individual commands should be similar.  Call parse_token() and place tokens in dynamic array commant_t::args.  Notice how I handled resizing of the dynamic array in the main loop.

```
int parse_command(char* str, command_t* command)
{
    int max_args = 16;

    if (!str || !command)
        return -1;

    command->argv = (char**)malloc(max_args * sizeof(char*));
    if (!command->argv)
        return -1; 

    while (*str != 0)
    {
       /* insert code to resize command->argv as needed */
       /* here. */

       command->argv[command->argc] = parse_token(&str);
       if (!command->argv[command->argc])
           break;

       ++command->argc;
    }

    if (!command->argc)
    {
        free(command->argv);
        command->argv = NULL;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;          // success! 
}
```

The code above is not tested, nor has it been compiled, but it should help you get a bit closer to what you want to achieve.  It is rather naive and limited, as it does not handle comments, nor multi-line commands.  These could be handled directly in the main loop.  It also does not handle environment variables expansion, but that's a bit outside the scope of this discussion, and could be handled rather gracefully between steps 3 and 4.

Comment: `return strchr(string, ">") != NULL;` takes a character `'>'`, not a string-literal `">"` (but we know what you meant)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  will fix.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I implemented your loop and it works great for the most part.  I'm having difficulty figuring out how to parse an input string for | and > though.  I can't figure out how to split it into 2 or 3 separate parts to be tokenized for piping and redirects.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes.  strtok  is not a very good tool for parsing complex strings.  You need to implement a proper parser.  I won't say that is an easy task, but the shell syntax is not too complex.   To properly cut a string into useful tokens, you must examine the input string byte by byte and assemble tokens, keeping track of open quotes, parens and the likes.

Comment: @Cemetery_Gates  See edited response with discussion about your overall architecture.